# When should 226 be sent from the FTP server?

Tags: ftp, ftp-server

I'm creating an FTP server in Qt, and I'm not sure when to send the 226 success response code for a RETR command.

Do I send it after all the data is written, but before the data connection socket is closed:

```
    reply(226);
    dataSocket()->disconnectFromHost();
```

or do I send it after the data connection socket is closed:

```
    dataSocket()->disconnectFromHost();
    dataSocket()->waitForDisconnected();
    reply(226);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt

> To prevent a race condition here, the server sends a reply (226) after closing the data connection.

Comment: Thanks. I think that `waitForDisconnected` is needed, otherwise the socket might not yet be closed, as `disconnectFromHost` is asynchronous.

Comment: @satuon: In that case, yes; I had no idea about the framework you were using so didn't consider that.